# Receiving Domain Emails using Amazon AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AWS SES for sending emails using my domain name.
The sending works fine. But now I want to receive all the emails sent using my domain like abc@example.com in SES.

I am trying to receive emails using rule set defined to execute Lambda function or to store emails in S3 bucket.

When I try to send email using gmail to my domain email, it is not received in S3 bucket and Lambda function is also not executed.

I have done following things so far:

1. Verified my domain with SES, (CNAME, TXT entries on my DNS provider
   i.e. GoDaddy)

   Added MX record for my domain in DNS settings

   Defined rule set for receiving emails for abc@example.com & store
   emails in S3 bucket.

Right now when I send email to this address I don't get anything in S3 bucket. I don't even receive delivery failure notification (This means MX record is working fine with my domain provider)

Please help.

Comment: I have exactly the same situation a year later after your question. I did the same steps... Have you solved it?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I am also having the same problem.

Comment: @After_Sunset that's a very old question & at that time I was exploring things around AWS SES. Unfortunately, currently, I am not working with that & don't remember if I ever solved that. Please check the upvoted answer if it helps.

Answer (score 4):

This question is over a year old, and I assume you've tried sending an email from a service other than gmail. It sounds as though your MX records may still be pointing to your GoDaddy instance, or at least one with a high enough priority. You can try running an MX query to verify this. Perhaps use an online lookup service, such as https://mxtoolbox.com to see if your MX Record(s) are published and where they are pointing, and priorities, etc.

In my experience, I've typically used Route53 to manage the DNS entries for SES-hosted applications as all necessary CNAME, TXT and MX records are set for you for domain name, SPF, DKIM and other verifications.

Ensure that the appropriate Rule Set is the "Active Rule Set" and that you do not have rule that acts as a "catch-all" with a higher priority.

Good luck!

Comment: You might not have an active rule set. That's one place to check!